# PHP pages on IIS say No input file specified

Tags: php, iis, windows-10

I'm trying to setup PHP on IIS on windows 10 pro workstation.

I have php 8.0.1 installed:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> php --version
PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2021 23:43:33) ( NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

In `php.ini` I tried setting both of the following (one at a time) and restarting IIS:

```
doc_root = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"
doc_root =
```

In IIS module mappings I have a module setup with:

```
Request path: '*.php'
Module: FastCgiModule
Executable Path: 'C:\php\php-cgi.exe'
```

I have verified that file is there on the filesystem.

And the result is the same. I see `No input file specified.` anytime I bring up a php page, including php.info.

How can I correct this?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: Thanks. What's Jexus Manager?

Comment: Thanks! I followed this link the in instructions you gave me, and now it's working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php#13-download-and-install-php-manually

Comment: You can post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: OK thanks, I will.